# Vuejs resources manage POST response [object Object]

Tags: http-post, vuejs2

I'm using vuejs-resource with this method to retrieve data from a remote API:

```
sendData() {
  this.$http.post('/test/', idatiditest).then(response => {
    this.resp = response.status;
    response.statusText;
    response.headers.get('Expires');
    this.resp = response.body;

  }, response => {
    // error callback
    this.resp = response.status + ' ' + response.statusText + ' ' + response.url + ' ' + response.body +
    response.headers;
  });

}
```

from dev tools>network  of chrome I can see the data:

```
{data_documento: ["La data è in un formato errato. Usa uno dei seguenti formati: YYYY[-MM[-DD]]."],…}
data_consegna
:
["La data è in un formato errato. Usa uno dei seguenti formati: YYYY[-MM[-DD]]."]
0
:
"La data è in un formato errato. Usa uno dei seguenti formati: YYYY[-MM[-DD]]."
data_documento
:
["La data è in un formato errato. Usa uno dei seguenti formati: YYYY[-MM[-DD]]."]
0
:
"La data è in un formato errato. Usa uno dei seguenti formati: YYYY[-MM[-DD]]."
data_riferimento
:
["La data è in un formato errato. Usa uno dei seguenti formati: YYYY[-MM[-DD]]."]
0
:
"La data è in un formato errato. Usa uno dei seguenti formati: YYYY[-MM[-DD]]."
```

But in the response.body I get:

> 400 Bad Request /test/ [object Object][object Object]

How can I read  the response.body data?

has asked in comments this is  the console output of my request data, I can't manage to see the response in console:

```
  idatiditest
    10:17:19.878
    {id: 5, data_documento: 4, rif: 4, cod: "4", qta: "4", …}

            __proto__
        :
    constructor
    :
    ƒ Object()
    hasOwnProperty
    :
    ƒ hasOwnProperty()
    isPrototypeOf
    :
    ƒ isPrototypeOf()
    propertyIsEnumerable
    :
    ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
    toLocaleString
    :
    ƒ toLocaleString()
    toString
    :
    ƒ toString()
    valueOf
    :
    ƒ valueOf()
    __defineGetter__
    :
    ƒ __defineGetter__()
    __defineSetter__
    :
    ƒ __defineSetter__()
    __lookupGetter__
    :
    ƒ __lookupGetter__()
    __lookupSetter__
    :
    ƒ __lookupSetter__()
    get __proto__
    :
    ƒ __proto__()
    set __proto__
    :
    ƒ __proto__()
```

Comment: console.log your `idatiditest`

Comment: it's not a problem with the data sended by the POST, the response is correct, the data are invalid. The response is readable, but I don't get it in the vuejs Object

Comment: like i said console log the data... i can't help without known what you get i the response

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it all comes down to the request config. Add the following config to your POST requests. The config is the 3rd argument of the http call. Within GO, you will now be able to use r.ForValue() to get your data.

```
var reqConfig = {
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    },
    'emulateJSON': true
};

this.$http.post('/test/', idatiditest, reqConfig).....
```